The WinError126 error keeps appearing in the pytorch part of TTS.api. Is there a way to fix it?
Code:
from TTS.api import TTS 
tts = TTS("tts_models/multilingual/multi-dataset/xtts_v2", gpu=False) 
tts.tts_to_file(text="It took me quite a long time to develop a voice, and now that I have it I'm not going to be silent.",file_path="output.wav",speaker_wav="nokotan.wav",language="en")  

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\luke\Desktop\youtube auto\ttstest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TTS.api import TTS
  File "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\TTS\api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from torch import nn
  File "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 143, in <module> 
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] 지정된 모듈을 찾을 수 없습니다. Error loading "C:\Users\luke\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I have tried uninstalling torch and reinstalling it, but no help.
Any help will be appreciated. thanks
